# JQuery, click меняет класс и запускается 1 раз

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот код:

```
$('.icon-heart-empty').click(
        function(){
            $(this).attr('class','icon-heart');
        }
);
$('.icon-heart').click(
        function(){
            $(this).attr('class','icon-heart-empty');
        }
);
```

При клике на объект с классом `icon-heart-empty` класс меняется, но при втором клике на этот объект должно срабатывать событие на новый класс, однако его нет. Если первоначально поставить просто `icon-heart`, ситуация такая же. Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо

```
$('.icon-heart').click(...);
```

надо

```
$(document).on('click','.icon-heart',...);
```

тогда будут обрабатываться события на динамически созданных/модифицированных элементах.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
$('body').on("click",".icon-heart-empty", function(){ $(this).attr('class','icon-heart'); } ); $('body').on("click",".icon-heart",  function(){ $(this).attr('class','icon-heart-empty'); } );
```

Answer (score 0):

может тебе стоит сделать вот так ?

```
 <div class="icon icon-heart-empty"></div>
 $('.icon').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('icon-heart-empty icon-heart');
  var hasClass = $(this).hasClass('icon-heart');
  if(hasClass){
   alert('test');   
  }else{
   alert('test2');
 }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5ow2zc0L/